# Why does the Microsoft Identity Web API middleware refuse to authenticate the access token?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, f#, azure-ad-msal

I am having issues authenticating my ASP.NET Core web api.

I have a SPA client made using React + Fable. Using Msal I getting the access token without issue, and I am sending it inside the Authorization header over to the web API. In particular, I am using the Vite dev server on which the SPA frontend is hosted on to proxy the requests from the frontend to backend.

1. Since I have the token from Azure AD, can I assume that everything is fine on the client side?
2. Here are the contents of my appsettings.json.

```json
    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "Domain": "simple-login-page.com",
        "TenantId": "ec88369d-6c2f-4f15-b0c7-adbe35caec77",
        "ClientId": "fd12b58b-6c39-4f86-ba02-98e6d7ee5eb5",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    },
```

Am I missing anything here? I've verified that the ids match the ones in the client.

3. Here is my `Program.cs` for the server.

```cs
[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions(
        WebRootPath = "public"
        ))

    builder.Services
        .AddGiraffe()
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection "AzureAd")
        |> ignore

    let app = builder.Build()

    app
        .UseAuthentication()
        .Use(Func<HttpContext,RequestDelegate,Task>(fun ctx next -> task {
            if ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated then return! next.Invoke(ctx)
            else return! ctx.ForbidAsync()
        }))
        .UseFileServer()
        .UseGiraffe(webApp)

    app.Run()

    0 // Exit code
```

Whenever the server gets a request, I get an error message saying it failed validation for some key. Am I missing something here?

Do I maybe need to configure something on Azure AD to allow the server to use it? Here is [the full project](https://github.com/mrakgr/MIP-And-Giraffe/tree/2660cce98d4f3ba095a7c5768d221360e96f0762/SAFE%20Stack%20Login).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that unlike for a web app, a SPA + web api require a different Azure AD setup. The Web API needs to be exposed, it needs to have a scope, and the SPA needs to be linked to that scope. You also need to request that scope during the redirect login.

I made a [video](https://youtu.be/_Asoh5Uj0hE) showing how to set up a SPA login from start to finish.